# I need to add a nice text editor to my wordpress site so users can type into it

Tags: wordpress

I am wondering if there is any type of nice text editor I can add to my wordpress site for the front end. I want users to be able to type in it and send it to themselves. I would think a contact form of some kind, but I am not sure. This is what I am trying to achieve:

[image]

Comment: when you say type in it and send it to themselves, what exactly do you mean? Send it to themselves how? In what format? It's not currently clear exactly what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: So the left side is their writing homework assignments, and the right side will be a text editor so they can type their writing assignment and then send it to themselves. Is their a way to achieve this with a plugin or some type of other simple solution? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I reckon what you are looking for is a simple WYSIWYG editor. You could try adding [TinyMCE](http://www.tinymce.com/) which is a real simple and quick plugin, to wherever you'd like. Have a look at below:

```
<script src="http://tinymce.cachefly.net/4.2/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<script>tinymce.init({selector:'textarea'});</script>

<textarea>Easy! Is this what you were looking for?</textarea>
```

Then you can place this `<textarea>` above, in a `<div>` and style it as you like.

Hope this helped.

Comment: Yes that worked great, however is there a WordPress plugin or a short code that you know of that would make it super simple for someone like me. I guess I could keep this code handy but again if a WordPress plugin could handle this then that would be great. Any ideas about that?

Comment: Awesome! And as for the plugin, TinyMCE has a plugin for WordPress, but it only works for the admin's dashboard WYSIWYG editor (not front-end). I guess you can look into [this question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/17786/how-do-i-include-tinymce-editor-in-frontend), but again they are solving it by calling `wp_editor()` which can be a tad complicated to implement as well.

Comment: Also, have a look at [this plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7-wysiwyg-field/) and see what you can get out of it :)